# Exception while creating new file

Tags: android, android-studio

I am unable to figure out what is going wrong while creating new file, i have tested below code and it works fine, but in current project i am unable to create new file.

Create file:

```
public static File createFile() {
    final String SDCARD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    final String TEMP_FOLDER = SDCARD + File.separator + "AVL1" + File.separator + "temp";
    final String name = "myfile3.png";
    final File directory = new File(TEMP_FOLDER);
    File tst = null;
    try {
        tst = new File(TEMP_FOLDER, name);
        if (tst.exists())
            return tst;

        if (directory.exists()) {
            Log.i("fdbg", "directory exists");
            tst.createNewFile();
        } else {
            Log.i("fdbg", "directory not exists");
            directory.mkdirs();
            tst.createNewFile();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tst;
}
```

Exception:

```
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:941)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at app.name.Views.Activities.MainActivity.createTempFile(MainActivity.java:290)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at app.name.Views.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:149)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:934)
10-04 16:21:02.995 9533-9533/app.name W/System.err:     ... 15 more
```

App build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package.name"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
   //some repos
}

dependencies {
  //project dependencies
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
        />
```

Device API = 21

Comment: `myFile.mkdirs();
                myFile.createNewFile();`. You cannot create that file as a directory with that name already exists. Remove the mkdirs(). And remove the directory before you try again.

Comment: no luck, i can create file with createNewFile(); but in current project its not working anymore

Comment: You did not remove that directory.

Comment: see updated question

Comment: You did not tell if you deleted that directory.

Comment: `tst.mkdirs();`. ???? Why are you creating a directory with that same name again?

Comment: `Log.i("fdbg", "exists");`. Not very informative. `Log.i("fdbg", "exists: " + tst.getAbsolutePath());`.

Comment: creating if it does not exists, this code works fine if you copy and run at any device but the problem is i am unable to figure whats is wrong with my project.

Comment: And you are unable to answer my simple questions. Or if you can you did not answer them. I wonder why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124906/discussion-between-h4sn-and-greenapps).

Comment: are the permissions located in the right place? They need to be a sibiling of  `<application>`

Comment: yes they are, updated question

Comment: as per your chat convo, you mention " this code works fine if you copy and run at any device". Does the phone you are using have enough free space? What do you mean by "i have tested below code and it works fine"? Where and how have you tested and worked?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are testing this is on Android 6.0, If yes then you have to add some code for granting this permissions

Comment: I am aware of that, i have mentioned i am testing on api 21 lollipop

Comment: This is not an answer. You need to be specific